# How load two consecutive videos using p:media primefaces with quicktime?

Tags: jsf, video, primefaces, quicktime

I'm working with Eclipse Indigo and primefaces JSF
I have two different stream videos coming from files. To obtain use:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class pruebaControlador{

 private StreamedContent myVideo; // + setter & Getter
 private StreamedContent myVideo2; // + setter & Getter


 public void videoInputStream(){
  try{
    inputStream = new FileInputStream("c://folder//video1.mp4");
    myVideo = new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream,"video/quicktime");

    inputStream2 = new FileInputStream("c://folder//video2.mp4");
    myVideo2 = new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream2,"video/quicktime");
  }Catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

So far so good...

My jsf contains the following:

```
<ui:define name="contentCenter">
<h:form id="formCenter" enctype="multipart/form-data"
prependId="false">

<h:panelGrid columns="1" id="panelVideo">
<p:media id="video" value="#{pruebaControlador.myVideo}"
width="800" height="600" player="quicktime">

<f:param name="scale" value="tofit" /> 
<f:param name="autoPlay" value="true" />
<f:param name="controller" value="true" />
<f:param name="loop" value="false" />
<f:param name="volume" value="50" />
<f:param name ="qtnext1" value="<#{pruebaControlador.myVideo2}> T<myself>" />

</p:media>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</ui:define>
```

but does not open the video 2, apparently did not find the URL in which is stored the Stream of video2

Comment: sorry for the errors, its right now.

Comment: Apparently the variable #{pruebaControlador.myVideo} that coming from Bean has the url with the full path. Qtnext function requires only the file name. So the problem is to obtain the file name only. As you can get the name of StreamContent generated at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is possible. What you possibly could do is set a second `<p:media.../>` with the rendered attribute and say somehow with javascript when the first video finished then set the first `<p:media rendered="false"/>` and the second `<p:media rendered:"true"/>`. If you want more details about what I mean, I could try to provide you with more details.